# Regex that matches directory path excluding filepath

Tags: regex, directory

I'm looking for a regex pattern that I need for IIS. Basically I want it to match any directory path but reject file paths. I've searched all over with little luck.

Example: Match: /directory/content/css/
         Match: /directory/content/css
         Reject: /directory/content/css/main.css
         Reject: /directory/content/css/main.*anything*

!--Due to feedback I've made some changes (Apologies this is my first time on the forum)--!

So far I've put together this pattern: `^(\/.*)(.*)*[^.*]$`
It appears to start out ok accepting anything starting with / but it still accepts extensions.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Would something like this work for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Comment: what about directories with no trailing slash? `http://webroot/content/css`

Comment: or directories with dots.. with no trailing slash

Comment: ^ yup, that was what I was going to get at

Comment: What language do you use? You don't need regex for that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?:\..*(?!\/))+
```

This regex will match if you got a file path..

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wV8zR7)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well, excuse me.. just thought about reverse validation ;)

Comment: The reverse validation worked but I ran into some other issues. I ended up remaking my small app with MVC and used the routing features there.

Comment: This does not work for all file paths what if there is a `.` in one of the folder names?

Answer (score 0):

What about this
`\/.*?[\w:]+`

https://regex101.com/r/b4Y6Si/1

although it can leave / at the end