# Regex to find directory in text

Tags: regex, path

How do I find a path and file name in a block of text?

Before you mark this as duplicate I know questions about file paths exist

- [Regex for parsing directory and filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169008/regex-for-parsing-directory-and-filename) (does not match in a paragraph.)
- [Regex that matches directory path excluding filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056104/regex-that-matches-directory-path-excluding-filepath) (this one just match the file name, answer doesn't work for paragraphs, and doesn't address `.` or spaces)
- [java regular expression to match file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489582/java-regular-expression-to-match-file-path) (doesn't address `.` or spaces)
- [Regex for extracting filename from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363145/regex-for-extracting-filename-from-path) (doesn't address being in a paragraph)

For example

```
In file included from /some/directoy/3.33A.37.2/something else/dogs.txt,
                 from /some/directoy/something else/dogs.txt,
                 from /some/directoyr/3.33A.37.2/something else/dogs.txt,
                 from /var/log/xyz/10032008.log,
                 from /var/log/xyz/test.c:29:
Solution:
please the file something.h has to be alone without others include, it has to be present in release letter, 
in order to be included in /var/log/xyz/test.c and /var/log/xyz/test.h automatically
Other Note: 
The file something.c must contain the somethinge.h and not the ecpfmbsd.h because it doesn't contain C operative code.. everything good..
```

The following are the ideal matches:

```
/some/directoy/3.33A.37.2/something else/dogs.txt
/some/directoy/something else/dogs.txt
/some/directoyr/3.33A.37.2/something else/dogs.txt
/var/log/xyz/10032008.log
/var/log/xyz/test.c:29 (this is a tricky one, ok with out it)
/var/log/xyz/test.c
/var/log/xyz/test.h
```

Going further what if I find an answer how can I change it to work with `\` instead of `/` directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\/.*\.[\w:]+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP1eO3/2)**

[image]

Btw, if you want to allow backslashes in the path you can have:

```
[\\\/].*\.[\w:]+
```

Comment: You are fast to make changes.

Comment: This has a problem  what if I have this `something /var/log/xyz/10032008.log lude, it has to be present in release letter, in order to be included in /var/log/xyz/test.c:54546 automatically`

Comment: you can try with `\/.*\.[\w:\s]+` but this will break another matches

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be working:

`\/[^,:]*\.\w+`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR1sS1/2).

You can fine-tune this if you know the exact extensions, their lengths and what characters they have. As for me, `\w+` would do to match extensions.

Comment: Nice I like this one. It does both `\ /`. I am parsing "big data" I don't know any extension. I am hoping to make this as general as possible.